# python разбить строку в масиив

Tags: python

Есть строка

```
test = "123456789"
```

Как получить из строки такой вот массив?

```
np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(list(test), int).reshape(3, 3)
```